# Why do SpamAssassin and Razor2 penalize for specific domain name in HTML body?

Tags: email, razor, spam, spamassassin

We are an ESP provider from Czech Republic, Europe. Our clients are regular Czech companies with their own client database. Since yesterday, we have a problem with our domains used in emails for online version, logout link and tracking the links. We are receiving a bad score because of these domain names.

**The score is, e.g.:**

RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_51_100 = 0.365

RAZOR2_CF_RANGE_E8_51_100 = 2.43

RAZOR2_CHECK = 1.729

We found out that one of our client probably sent a campaign on bought DB (100.000 addresses), so we blocked him, but now we need to solve this issue.

To buy a new domains is a solution, but not long-term solution. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Would it help that every user of our system would have (for these links in email) a subdomain like username.redirectdomain.com Or another solution—registering to some whitelist?

There should be a solution when you from 95% do not send spam and you don't want to replace your domains every week. HW and IP addresses we have solved well, we have problem with this penalization in email body—especially for domain names used for tracking the links (official links are replaced with ours).

Answer (score 5):

[Vipul's Razor](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708170551/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipul%27s_Razor) is a [hash sharing system](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/HashSharingSystem) based on two "signature" engines. The [Ephemeral](https://metacpan.org/release/TODDR/Razor2-Client-Agent-2.86/source/lib/Razor2/Signature/Ephemeral.pm) engine builds a digest of the message's body content (somewhat like a [fuzzy checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), though I might be projecting/misreading) while the [Whiplash](https://metacpan.org/release/TODDR/Razor2-Client-Agent-2.86/source/lib/Razor2/Signature/Whiplash.pm) engine does indeed look at linked hosts. These are then normalized and stored as SHA1 checksums.

You could consider Razor's listings of Whiplash checksums to be [blocklists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist_(computing)) (aka "blacklists") even though Razor is not a [DNSBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL). Razor's hashes are functionally similar to Google Safebrowsing's hashes—the hash server only knows hashes, not what they map to.

I believe Cloudmark runs Razor mostly on auto-pilot. While they do not accept allowlisting ("whitelisting") requests (see their [now-ancient FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20230315004845/https://razor.sourceforge.net/docs/faq.php)), you can add a delisting request to the [Vipul's Razor Support Requests](https://sourceforge.net/p/razor/support-requests/) queue.

I assume that, like most blocklists, listings will expire after some buffer period following the end of the spam campaigns that used them.  [M³AAWG's documents](https://www.m3aawg.org/published-documents), especially the [Help – I'm on a Blocklist](https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/maawg/files/news/M3AAWG_Blocklist_Help_BP_2014-06.pdf) guide, could provide the exact guidance you need.

If you want further help, specifically from within this industry, I'd suggest that your employer joins [M³AAWG](https://www.m3aawg.org/), which creates a venue for well-behaved [ESPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_service_provider_%28marketing%29) to meet with [ISPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) and other receivers as well as security companies (including Cloudmark, which owns and operates Razor, and its parent company Proofpoint).

Answer (score 1):

Razor2 is a blocklist, period.

It is a blocklist like every other blocklist, and despite their attempt to appear to be "trustworthy" where every user has a "trust" score, this list is also being fed from data that is collected from **spamtraps** in an automatic way. The mere fact that it is operated and owned by Cloudmark means that Cloudmark can set up their own trap accounts and give them a trust score of 100 very easily.  and why not?  it is their product now (Vipul stopped working there very long ago), their property, and they can choose what to do with it.

The only difference here, is that unlike other blocklists, you have no way of removing yourself from the list, and listing will automatically stop once the originating source that sent the blocked email ceases. So realy, the only way to have yourself not listed in it - is simply not to send emails to their spamtraps, and the only way to do that is to have **double opt in** or confirmed-opt in lists.

I have written a blog post about why [Razor2 is a blocklist](http://programmers-tips.blogspot.co.il/2017/01/razor2-blacklist-apparently-thats-what.html), where you can get some actual details about how and why it works the way it is.

Comment: Your blog post is extremely incorrect.  Razor2 was written by Vipul Ved Prakash, who then went on to found Cloudmark (they didn't "buy" it), and it uses locality-sensitive hashing (fuzzy matching) specifically to cluster content that changes its characteristics (such as sender IP or domain).  I've never heard anybody mention that it is a sender blocklist (because it's not).  It is a "_content_ blocklist" if you insist, but that term doesn't exist.  See my answer from 3 years ago for further detail.

Comment: I have updated [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/872728/209449) after reviewing more about Razor2. I still don't think it has a sender blocklist, but one of its two signature engines does effectively serve as a blocklist for the hosts linked in the message body.